# Disappearing chars at the end of TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, imageview, spannable

I am using **SpannableStringBuilder** to show image inside **TextView**. However, if the image will stay at the end of the line in TextView it just disappears. If I increase the size of the text it would be visible again. How can I fix it?

**This is the code how I added the image inside TextView**:

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(createClusterBitmap(idOfAyat)), ssb.length() - 1, ssb.length(), 0);
itemViewHolder.kuranArabic.setText(ssb);
```

**XML code of item**:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/kuranArabic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/scheherazade"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="?attr/color2"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_27sdp" />
```

**I have attached two images**. The first one is with an image that disappears when stays at end of the text view. The second one is visible when comes at the first position.

[image: First Picture]

[image: Second Picture]

[First Picture if StackOverflow's link doesn't work](https://pasteboard.co/K2X4UTw.jpg)

[Second Picture if StackOverflow's link doesn't work](https://pasteboard.co/K2X4gH0.jpg)

P.S. I would appreciate any help. It is one of my first questions, don't judge me so strongly. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by adding a flag called **Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE** to Spannable String Builder.

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(image), ssb.length() - 3, ssb.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
itemViewHolder.kuranArabic.setText(ssb);
```